# Menu object is coming null when it is getting called as a callback function

Tags: android

I have a requirement of placing a progressbar in the actionbar/toolbar. I am able to do it by following this link(http://www.michenux.net/android-refresh-item-action-bar-circular-progressbar-578.html).
However I am facing an issue in order to show and hide the progressbar, following the callback design pattern which I have used here. Below is code snippet -

```
    public interface ICallBack {
        void setRefreshActionButtonState(boolean b);
    }

    public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, ICallBack {
        private Menu optionsMenu;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_web);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());    
            webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            this.optionsMenu = menu;
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_base, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                // Logic to load the webview again 
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void setRefreshActionButtonState(boolean refreshing) {
            if (optionsMenu != null) {
                final MenuItem refreshItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
                if (refreshItem != null) {
                    if (refreshing) {
                        refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.toolbar_indeterminate_progress);
                    } else {
                        refreshItem.setActionView(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        ICallBack callBack;
        public MyWebViewClient(Activity context) {
            callBack = new MyFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            callBack.setRefreshActionButtonState(true);//Showing the progressbar
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            callBack.setRefreshActionButtonState(false);//Hiding the progressbar
        }
    }
```

When **setRefreshActionButtonState()** gets call then I am getting **optionsMenu** value as **null**, resulting not able to show and hide the progressbar.

Can someone help me to figure out that where I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: you cannot call getactivity() before the view is created.

Comment: Hi Rushi, Thanks for the reply. I believe getActivity() which is under onCreateOptionsMenu() gets call after onCreateView(). Please, let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload the xml where the item action_refresh is. The problem could be in `findItem(R.id.action_refresh);`

Comment: Hi @manolodewin, I am not sure if problem exist in xml file. However, here is the xml file - `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
         android:title="@string/menuitem_refresh"
         android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
         android:orderInCategory="1"
         android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>`  I am getting optionsMenu as null when it is getting call from onPageStarted() and onPageFinished() which is in MyWebViewClient class.